Exponential decay for Bernoulli percolation with a ghost field
Background on Bernoulli percolation:
Consider the hypercubic lattice $\mathbb{Z}^d$ as a graph with vertices as point of integer coordinates and edges between points of distance 1.
Now, delete every edge with probability $1-p$, for some number $p \in [0,1]$. This model is called Bernoulli percolation with parameter $p$.
We consider the probability that there is path from 0 to a vertex of distance at least $n$ away for some real number $n$.  We denote this quantity
$\mathbb{P}_p[0 \leftrightarrow \partial \Lambda_n].$ Here $\Lambda_n$ is the box of size $n$ and $\partial \Lambda_n$ is its boundary.
Now, it is classic, that there is a (sharp) phase transition. In the sense that for every dimension $d \geq 2$ there is a number $p_c \in (0,1)$ such that
$\mathbb{P}_p[0 \leftrightarrow \partial \Lambda_n] \leq C e^{- \mu n}$  for $p <  p_c$
and
$\mathbb{P}_p[0 \leftrightarrow \partial \Lambda_n] \geq C $
for some constant $C > 0$.
Bernoulli percolation with a ghost:
Now suppose that I add one additional vertex $g$ to the graph in such a way that there is a path from every vertex $v$ in the graph to the $g$. Where I delete every edge in the original graph with probability $1-p$, in this graph I delete each of the new edges with probability $1-h$ independently.
In this setup, let us consider the probability that there is path from 0 to a vertex of distance at least $n$ away such that there is no path from $0$ to the ghost.  $\mathbb{P}[g \not \leftrightarrow 0 \leftrightarrow \partial \Lambda_n]$.
In this setup,  for all $p \in [0,1]$ as long as $h>0$ it holds that
$$\mathbb{P}[g \not \leftrightarrow 0 \leftrightarrow \partial \Lambda_n] \leq e^{- c(h) n}.$$
To see that, just note that for every step in the $n$-step path from 0 to $\partial \Lambda_n$, there is a positive probability that 0 connects to the ghost.
The question:
Now, suppose that I know that for an annulus $A_{K,2K} = \Lambda_{2K} \setminus \Lambda_K$  that the probability that there is a circuit in the annulus, such that the cluster of the circuit in the annulus is connected to the ghost is at least $q$.
Does it hold that for all $n$ that
$$\mathbb{P}[g \not \leftrightarrow 0 \leftrightarrow \partial \Lambda_n] \leq e^{- c(q) n}?$$
where $c(q)$ depends only on $q$ and not on $K$.
My progress:
My intuition is that in every step of length $K$ that the path takes away from $0$ there is a positive probability that it randomly "runs into" a circuit which is connected to the ghost.
The problem with that however is some degree of negative information. But I think that the cluster from $0$ to $n$ by the pattern theorem or a variation thereof can used to prove that every pattern in terms of explored boxes of size $K$ will be seen many times as $n$ increases. When I explore the cluster of $0$ one box of size $K$ after another, in many patterns there is no negative information.
